# Owncloud 10.0.2 E-Mail Template not editable

Tags: owncloud

I installed OwnCloud 10.0.2 (stable) using the Auto-Install script on a Webspace.

Everything seems to work perfectly except for the mail templates. Whenever I try to edit one of them, a window pops up that says "template not editable". Also, there is no example theme in the themes folder. Could that be related?

I already found this, but the issue doesn't seem to be fixed...
https://github.com/owncloud/templateeditor/issues/54

Can anybody help? :)

Thanks in advance,
Moritz

Comment: also getting this, issue still not fixed it seems